# Shiny plot doesn't change with inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am an absolute beginner to Shiny, so I would appreciate your patience and any advice to my issue. Here's the server function that I'm using to output a ggplot, which works on its own, but doesn't change at all when I change the inputs:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plooot<-renderPlot({
    df = df %>%
    group_by(input$Category,Type) %>%
    summarise(Distribution=sum(Distribution))
    ggplot(df,aes(input$Category,Distribution,fill=Type))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Here's my ui function as well just for reference:

```
ui <- fluidPage(    

  titlePanel("chart"),

  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      

    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Category","Category:",choices=c("a","b","c","d","e","f")),
      selectInput("a","a:", choices=unique(Table$a), selected="All"),
      selectInput("b","b:", choices=unique(Table$b), selected="All"),
      selectInput("c","c:", choices=unique(Table$c), selected="All"),
      selectInput("d","d:", choices=unique(Table$d), selected="All"),
      selectInput("e","e:", choices=unique(Table$e), selected="All"),
      selectInput("f","f:", choices=unique(Table$f), selected="All")
    ),

    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plooot")  
    )

  )
)
```

Unfortunately, I can't post the data for legal reasons, but here are two plots of what I want vs. what I have: 
[image: This is want I want. This separates each category into its options and then plots two bars (the fill) for each option]

[image: This is what I get from shiny. It separates the entire dataset into the two fill options, and nothing changes when I change the inputs.]

This is probably a very rudimentary mistake, but I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `group_by(input$Category,Type)` needs an actual column (using NSE), not a `character` (which is what it gets from `input$Category`). Look for standard-evaluation versions of the `dplyr` verbs.

Comment: For reference: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: Try `ic <- enquo(input$Category)` and then `... %>% group_by(!!ic,Type) ...`.

Comment: I am not sure how you are storing the data (df) in the app, but `df = df %>% ....` might overwrite your data when you generate the plot making it impossible to update to plot after an input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @AndS., re-assigning back to `df = ...` is not likely what you want/need but will almost certainly irreversibly reduce your data. Additionally, `input$Category` is a `character` and not a `symbol` that `group_by` is expecting. Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(    
  titlePanel("chart"),
  # Generate a row with a sidebar
  sidebarLayout(      
    # Define the sidebar with one input
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Category","Category:",choices=colnames(mtcars))
    ),
    # Create a spot for the barplot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plooot")  
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plooot<-renderPlot({
    req(input$Category)
    icq <- sym(input$Category)
    mtcars %>%
      group_by(!!!icq, vs) %>%
      summarise(disp=sum(disp)) %>%
      ggplot(aes_string(input$Category, "disp", fill="vs")) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Great example. I think `aes_string()` is (sort of) deprecated. We can make use of quosures in ggplot2 as well if we wrap `sym` in `quo`. `icq <- quo(!!sym(input$Category))` then call `group_by(!!icq, vs)` and `ggplot(aes(!!icq, disp, fill=vs))`

Comment: @AndS., I thought so, but I admit to not having completely "mastered" the `quosure` scene yet. Thanks for the code hints!

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your data looks like, see below. The best thing to do is for any data set that will be affected by a user input, is to put it in a reactive expression. Then use that reactive expression in your output plots. I also added an "ALL" to your choices and an if function in case you want to see them all together like you have in your picture.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Chart"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Category","Category:",choices=c("All","a","b","c","d","e","f"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("Plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Distribution <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,2,4)
  Category <- c("a","b","c","e","f","a","b","c","e","f")
  Type <- c("Blue","Blue","Blue","Blue","Blue","Red","Red","Red","Red","Red")

  df <- data.frame(Distribution ,Category,Type)

  df_subset <- reactive({

    if (input$Category == "All") {df}
    else{df[df$Category == input$Category,]}
  })

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({

    dat <- df_subset()

    dat <- dat %>%
      group_by(Category,Type) %>%
      summarise(Distribution=sum(Distribution))

    plot <- ggplot(dat,aes(Category,Distribution,fill=Type))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
    return(plot)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

[image]
[image]